# Google map taking more time to load

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google map in my website to show marker and to draw marker I also use an extra JS `markerwithlabel.js`.

To initialize map what have I done

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', mapInitFunction);
```

it working fine when I don't use third party resources.

For my business purpose I have to load some third party JS, images etc, sometimes one of these resources get loading. Because `request` status show pending. Consequently Google map not load. Since I have initialize map in window load. I read [Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels) but didn't get any 
alternative way to initialize Google map without window load.

Any of your suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use callback function method and put it at the end of body

```
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**YOUR_KEY**&callback=mapInitFunction" async defer></script>
```

You can use without async defer attributes as well. It just provides a way of lazy loading the google maps

Comment: There are two way only.. 1 does not meet your requirement other is not supported. Solution seems here is to find the alternative to markerlabel.js library or change the source of it to support callback mechanism